# Trouble updating a Shopify variant's inventory quantity via PUT

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, shopify

I'm attempting to update variant inventory quantities via the API using the XML version of one of the PHP API libs, but am having problems. I feel like I'm really close but so far all I'm getting back is "Error" ... nothing more specific than that.

While it's true this is similar to another question here, that question was answered with "your library is outdated, use one of these." I don't have the luxury of time to swap out or experiment with different libs at this point. I need to get this one working.

SO, here's what I'm passing via cURL "PUT":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<variant>
   <inventory-quantity type="integer">123456</inventory-quantity>
   <id type="integer">123456789</id>
</variant>
```

And here's what is being returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
   <errors>Error</errors>
</hash>
```

My function is as follows:

```
function updateProductVariant($id,$qty) {
    $url = $this->buildDataURL('variants/'.$id);

    $string = '<variant>
   <id type="integer">'.$id.'</id>
   <inventory-quantity type="integer">'.$qty.'</inventory-quantity>
</variant>';

    $simpleXML = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
    $xml = $simpleXML->asXML();

    $putData = tmpfile();
    fwrite($putData,$xml);
    fseek($putData,0);

    $result = $this->curlPost($url,$xml,$putData);
    return $xml . "\n" . $result;
    #return $result;
}
```

The cURL function is as follows:

```
function curlPost($url,$request=null,$put=null,$post=null) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if ($put) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $put);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($request));
    }
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-length: '.strlen($request)));
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
    } else {
        $result = curl_errno($ch).": ".curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

At this point I'm guessing it's an issue with cURL or PUT, or both, but without specific error data it's hard for me to know what's up. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Content type header isn't being set for put requests.

Comment: Cripes... I can't believe I missed that. Thanks, John. <smacking head on desk>